# SSL is not working for my AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I have created a HTTPS Load Balancer for my EC2 instace and created a certificate in the AWS Certificate Manager for *.example.net

I associated this certificate to the HTTPS Load Balancer. I have added the security group to open the port 443 in both Load Balancer and the EC2 instance.

https://www.example.com works. But If I mention without www its not working. That is if I give the URL https://example.com, I am getting untrusted certificate error.

Could anybody tell me what I am missing or doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I'd start by reading this: http://serverfault.com/questions/310530/should-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-secure-both-the-root-domain-as-well-as-the-sub Also, you don't need to open port 443 on the EC2 instance if the SSL termination is happening on the ELB.

Comment: Thank you Mark. It makes sense to me. Do I have to request for another certificate or is there a way to update the subjectAltNames in the existing certificate?

Comment: Certificates are immutable, @Sree.  You have to replace it with a new one matching your needs.

Answer (score -1):

you need two different certificates: one for example.com and one for *.example.com.

You can generate a new one with AWS.

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but this is wrong in one important  way... specifically, each ELB supports only one certificate per listener, and there's only one relevant listener, port 443.  The correct answer is to request one new ACM certificate with all of the desired domain names and/or wildcards, e.g. both `example.com` and `*.example.com`.